# Import of org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoRuntime, org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession and org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoView not working in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, gecko, geckoview

For creating browser I need Mozilla GeckoView.
I did exact the steps of this [link](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView), but when I try to import the packages above, theres a compiler error.

```
import org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoRuntime;
import org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession;
import org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoView;
```

I copied this to the Main activity.
Did I do anything wrong, or does anybody know how to fix this?

**settings.gradle
**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.mozilla.org/maven2/"
        }
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "SauspielA11GeckoView"
include ':app'
```

**build.gradle
**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chrome.sauspiela11geckoview"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

ext {
    geckoviewChannel = "nightly"
    geckoviewVersion = "108.0.20221215175817"
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation "org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-${geckoviewChannel}:${geckoviewVersion}"
}
```

**MainActivity.java
**

```
package com.chrome.sauspiela11geckoview;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoRuntime;
import org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession;
import org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: An error text might help community to answer the question

Answer (score 1):

Into **build.gradle** just change this line:

```
implementation "org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview-${geckoviewChannel}:${geckoviewVersion}"
```

to

```
implementation "org.mozilla.geckoview:geckoview:113.0.20230501151611"
```

NB: geckoview is stable now!

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
ext {
    geckoviewChannel = "nightly"
    geckoviewVersion = "108.0.20221215175817"
}
```

By:

```
ext {
    geckoviewChannel = "x86_64" // arm64-v8a or channel desired
    geckoviewVersion = "108.0.20221215175817"
}
```

Channels and versions: https://maven.mozilla.org/?prefix=maven2/org/mozilla/geckoview/